# how to store data into snowflake having timestamp TIMESTAMP_NTZ using pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

Hello I am using below code for loading data from spark (pyspark) dataframe to snowflake table I am getting error like **Timestamp '2020-06-15T12:00:20.040Z' is not recognized.**
please find below code for the same

sfOptionsRaw1 = {
"sfURL" : "test",
"sfUser" : "test",
"sfPassword" : "test",
"sfDatabase" : "test",
"sfSchema"  : "test",
"sfWarehouse" : "test",
"sfrole" : "test",
"TIMESTAMP_TYPE_MAPPING" : "TIMESTAMP_NTZ",
"TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT" : "YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3"
}

test1.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).option("dbtable", "test").option("columnmap", "Map(type -> type_test1 )").options(**sfOptionsRaw1).mode("append").save()

**After executing above cpde I get below error**

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2088.save.
: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: Timestamp '2020-06-15T12:00:20.040Z' is not recognized
File 'NVefrmAwkn.csv', line 1, character 63
Row 1, column "_TEST1"["TIME_TEST1":4]
If you would like to continue loading when an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or 'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeUtil.checkErrorAndThrowException(SnowflakeUtil.java:102)
at net.snowflake.client.core.StmtUtil.execute(StmtUtil.java:410)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeHelper(SFStatement.java:371)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQueryInternal(SFStatement.java:195)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.executeQuery(SFStatement.java:147)
at net.snowflake.client.core.SFStatement.execute(SFStatement.java:529)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.executeInternal(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:204)
at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeStatementV1.execute(SnowflakeStatementV1.java:239)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:261)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$executeInterruptibly$1.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:261)
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper$$anonfun$3.apply(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:283)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the timestamp parameter to this:

`"TIMESTAMP_NTZ_OUTPUT_FORMAT" : "YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS.FF3Z"`

This format matches the format that you are showing in your post, so it might fix your issue.

Comment: Mike thanks for your response but it not working same error